# Ionic 2: Disable Modal Dismissing on Back Button (Android)

Tags: android, ionic2

Is there a simpler way of preventing the hardware back button on Android from dismissing a modal other than handling the entire back button functionality (platform.registerBackButtonAction), something like the [enableBackdropDismiss](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/#advanced) option?

I'm implementing a login page as a modal, so I need to prevent users from simply pressing the back button to dismiss it. I'm starting to think though, that using a modal for a login page is a bad design choice.

Answer (score 3):

I tried other solutions and ATM, I think not; you could create and inject a derived ModalCtrl, in create method return a derived Modal and ModalImpl, and in the latter override some dismiss logic. It's not great, and the ionic guys [seem to have a plan](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-avoid-the-hardware-back-button-to-close-a-modal-view-in-android/57432) - hopefully for fixing ionViewCanLeave.

The following seems a minimal solution for blocking/unblocking modal dismiss on Android back:

```
class LoginModal {

  private backButtonUnregister: any;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    this.backButtonUnregister = platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {});
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.backButtonUnregister();
  }
}
```

As to using a modal for login: Upon first login, we're merely setting a login page as the root page. However, upon reauthentication, eg. when resuming from background, we're pushing a login modal. This has the advantage of blocking the (burger)menu and overlaying all other pages (including other modals, which would otherwise overlay the reauth page).